# Three JS Slider transition with shader?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, slider, shader, react-three-fiber

I love shaders because it gives a beautiful effects & and i saw alot of slider effects like this one

```
https://codepen.io/dev_loop/pen/eYZqMwV
```

I tried alot to implement the same logic animation into my slider below but couldn't figure out how this is done because he is animation images not 3d models , is there anyway to animate the 3d models with the same effect as the WEBGL Slider above when the user slide to the right and left ?

I made a small slider in react with useGesture to move slides right and left with onDrag event

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useGesture } from "react-use-gesture";
import { Float, OrbitControls, Box, Ring, Stage } from "@react- 
three/drei";
export default function App() {
 const models = [
 { model: <Box /> },
{ model: <Ring innerRadius={0.5} outerRadius={1} /> },
{ model: <Box /> },
{ model: <Ring innerRadius={0.5} outerRadius={1} /> },
{ model: <Box /> },
{ model: <Ring innerRadius={0.5} outerRadius={1} /> }
  ];

const [modelIndex, setModelIndex] = useState(0);
const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);
const [canChangeModel, setCanChangeModel] = useState(true);
const modelCount = models.length;
const bind = useGesture({
onDragStart: () => {
  setIsDragging(true);
},
onDragEnd: () => {
  setIsDragging(false);
  setCanChangeModel(true);
},
onDrag: ({ direction }) => {
  if (isDragging && canChangeModel) {
    const threshold = 0.5;

    if (direction[0] < -threshold) {
      setModelIndex((index) => (index + 1) % modelCount);
      setCanChangeModel(false);
    } else if (direction[0] > threshold) {
      setModelIndex((index) => (index - 1 + modelCount) % 
modelCount);
      setCanChangeModel(false);
    }
  }
}
});

return (
<div style={{ height: "100vh" }} {...bind()}>
  <Canvas>
    <ambientLight />
    <pointLight position={[10, 10, 10]} />

    <group>
      {models.map(
        (model, index) =>
          index === modelIndex && <group key={index}>{model.model}</group>
      )}
    </group>
  </Canvas>
</div>
);
}
```

Is It possible to get the above effect transition between slides and add it to my slides below ?

Comment: Please explain what you need and what you've tried a bit better, as it stands your question is hard to answer. Also, please add relevant code into the question itself instead of using code sharing websites.

Comment: I will edit the example above , I tried to copy the vertex/fragment shaders and added these effects inside an EffectComposer but it doesn't work , i kept trying to add it every where but i failed , i am not sure where to add the shader effect that he made between slides to my 3d models slider.

Comment: I edited the post with the 3d slider , but i wanted to paste the codepen part so people can see what is the animation looks like